# How to set ratio / knee on Dynamic Processor Audio Unit

Tags: ios, macos, avfoundation, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I struggle to understand all params of Apple's Dynamic Processor Audio Unit (`kAudioUnitSubType_DynamicsProcessor`).

In most Audio Editing apps (Garage Band etc), Compressor (aka Dynamic Processor) has a **"ratio" and "knee"** knob.

1. There is no '*knee*' parameter in Apple's Dynamic Processor. There's a `kDynamicsProcessorParam_ExpansionThreshold` - is that what people are referring as `knee`?
2. There is a `kDynamicsProcessorParam_ExpansionRatio` but I noticed additional comment about it:

> Note that the dynamics processor does not have fixed compression ratios.
> Instead, `kDynamicsProcessorParam_HeadRoom` adjusts the amount of compression.
> Lower `kDynamicsProcessorParam_HeadRoom` values results in higher compression.
> The compression ratio is automatically adjusted to not exceed `kDynamicsProcessorParam_Threshold + kDynamicsProcessorParam_HeadRoom` values.

I dont fully understand how to interpret `headRoom`. Is it ok if I just set `expansionRatio` or should I only set `headRoom`?
Can you please help me understand which parameters should I adjust when the user is using a "Ratio" knob in UI?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone struggling to understand kAudioUnitSubType_DynamicsProcessor or other kAudioUnitType_Effect types, you can play around with these in Garage Band by first enabling Audio Unit effects, then adding them to a track:
[image: Using Audio Unit effects in Garage Band]

Comment: Wow, that's an awesome tip! Thanks!